# default initialization of double array of pointers in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, default-value

I'm curious if these are zero initialized and all my pointers are 0 when I declare a fixed size array. I can say `foo* arr[1000][1000]` and I see that all the entries are 0..but I am not sure if this is something I can rely on or not. I could say `foo* arr[1000][1000] = {}` but this double array is a member variable in a class and I wouldn't want to have a double for loop in the constructor if it's not necessary...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on how you allocate the array.

If it's `static` or global, then the contents will all be initialised to 0. If it's a local variable, then the contents won't be initialised to anything.

So since your array is a member variable, it won't be initialised to 0 automatically. However, you can initialise all the variables to zero by using the initialisation list in the constructor thusly:

```
struct A {
    //    VVV   value-initialises the contents of arr
    A() : arr() { }

    double arr[x][y];
};
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the context. If the array is defined at namespace level, then static initialization will set all pointers to null for you. If it is defined in a function scope or as a member of a class, there is no such guarantee.

Since it is a member of a class, it will not be correctly initialized, so you will need to initialize it manually. You can do so by adding `arr()` to the initialization list. Being pointers, you can use `memset` to set the whole array to 0 in a single call (which will also be as efficient as it gets), but beware, this only works for `POD` types.

Comment: In practice, maybe.  As far as the standard is concerned, what you get when using `memset` on a pointer is undefined behavior; there's no guarantee that a null pointer is all bits set to zero.  Using `std::fill` is likely to be faster as well.